# Go extension in VS Code: go.languageServerExperimentalFeatures not recognized or outdated in setting.json

Tags: go, vscode-extensions

[image]I have been using the Go extension for VS Code, and a particular feature was functioning well until last week. However, it has stopped working now. When I check the setting.json file, it shows an error stating 'unknown feature' or 'outdated' for go.languageServerExperimentalFeatures:

```
  "go.languageServerExperimentalFeatures": {
        "autoComplete": true,
        "documentSymbols": true,
        "findReferences": true,
        "format": true,
        "goToDefinition": true,
        "goToTypeDefinition": true,
        "hover": true,
        "signatureHelp": true,
        "rename": true,
        "workspaceSymbols": true,
    }
```

I tryed to uninstall both extension go nighty and go then installed still not works.

Comment: The `go.languageServerExperimentalFeatures` setting was deprecated. See [Release 0.39.0](https://github.com/golang/vscode-go/releases/tag/v0.39.0) specifically Removed go.languageServerExperimentalFeatures setting which was deprecated in v0.21.0. ([Issue 1109](https://github.com/golang/vscode-go/issues/1109))